# C# Load Script from SAP to SQL server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sap

I am working on setting up a program to display active MSDs in production as well as BakeTime, MSL, etc. I have created database tables in our sql server and was tasked with creating a c# program to pull the MSD data from SAP to my database tables, and I am not sure where to start? (I was told that using Entity Framework would help me in this process but I am just not sure where to begin)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract data from SAP to SQL Server and volume is expected to be large, one viable option would be to use SQL Server Integration Services with custom SSIS components for SAP. If you are proficient in C# and desire to write your own interface, you can leverage SAP .Net connector 3.0.

If volume is not huge, another way to consider is to expose SAP data through SAP's own OData interface and use C# to write a custom solution to consume the OData endpoints. This is also a well established pattern, with some required development work in SAP.

But based upon the way you asked, I would say just go with SSIS and commercial components (disclaimer: we offer such components) to get your project delivered in timely manner.